# Doctrine ResultMapping Collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Something like this works very good to run a native query and mapp the results into an entity.

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Application\Entity\A', 't1');
$rsm->addFieldResult('t1', 'A_ID', 'A_ID');
$rsm->addFieldResult('t1', 'A_Name', 'A_Name');
$sql = 'SELECT t1.A_ID,t1.A_Name FROM A t1';
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
```

But how can i make this work if i have a collection in Entity A.

```
/**
 * @access protected
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\B")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="AB",joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="B_ID", unique=true)})
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $Bs;
```

Is there a way to map this with ResultSetMapping?

THANKS

Comment: I think you need to join Application\Entity\B... this is like its done in the query builder but I never used ResultSetMapping before so this is just an opinion.

Comment: Yea id did that. But the problem is, that Bs is a arraycollection and not a simple association.